# Making an image link in a table

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

Does somebody know how to make a link form this image?
Do I have to change "background" to "img src"?
Or do I have to change the `<a href>`?

```
<a href="index.html"><td  height="117" colspan="4" background="afbeeldingen/klein-2kolom_04.gif"></a>&nbsp;</td>
```

Comment: What have you tried? In the time you have taken to ask this question, you could have tested several different ways.

Comment: I tried different things with <a href>, it is Javascript, in HTML it will be work. I'm working with tables, so maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Why did you end the `<a>` tag before you ended the `<td>` tag?

Comment: Why are you wrapping an anchor _around_ a `td`? What exactly do you want to do here? Can you explain, in your questions, in clear terms, what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I find out that it has nothing to do with the code. The image is integrated into another image, so I can not edit it. It is not my code and not my design, so one big puzzle.

Thank you all for your help, but it's better to give up this piece of S***!

Answer (score 2):

Backgrounds are backgrounds. Content is content. Links need to inform users about where they point and so require content. Table rows cannot have anchors as children. Table cells cannot have anchors as parents. The background attribute is obsolete.

```
<td>
    <a href="index.html">
        <img src="afbeeldingen/klein-2kolom_04.gif" alt="DON'T FORGET THIS">
    </a>
</td>
```

Comment: You are assuming the image is essential content. It may be just decoration and using it as background is more suitable... although I agree the background attribute should not be used and CSS instead

Comment: The question explicitly says that the image is the content being turned into a link.

Comment: Not really, the questioner had already applied it as a background. The filename also looks like a slice-up.

Comment: Yes really, see the first sentence of the question (not counting the title).

Comment: I find out that it has nothing to do with the code. The image is integrated into another image, so I can not edit it. It is not my code and not my design, so one big puzzle.

Thank you all for your help, but it's better to give up this piece of S***!

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the onClick event:

```
<td height="117" colspan="4" background="afbeeldingen/klein-2kolom_04.gif" onclick="location.href='index.html';">&nbsp;</td>
```

Comment: Producing a 'link" that only works with JavaScript and only with people using a pointing device (and not someone who uses a keyboard or other non-pointing device (either out of preference or handicap)).

Comment: True, but please stop downvoting everything you don't like. It still works.

Comment: Please don't assume that I'm responsible for downvoting this. And it doesn't "still work", it only works some of the time.

Comment: Sorry about that. I was just wondering why there are so many downvotes. I didn't vote anything here, just for the record... What non-pointing device besides keyboards are there?

Comment: Breath switches spring to mind (used by people paralysed from the neck down).

Comment: Agree, it's pretty lame how many downvotes there are already... it puts me off SO sometimes, too much peacocking! shame

Comment: I find out that it has nothing to do with the code. The image is integrated into another image, so I can not edit it. It is not my code and not my design, so one big puzzle.

Thank you all for your help, but it's better to give up this piece of S***!

Answer (score 0):

To use a css based solution

```
<td  height="117" colspan="4" background="afbeeldingen/klein-2kolom_04.gif">
  <a href="index.html">&nbsp;</a>
</td>
```

Apply the following css

```
td a {
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: I find out that it has nothing to do with the code. The image is integrated into another image, so I can not edit it. It is not my code and not my design, so one big puzzle.

Thank you all for your help, but it's better to give up this piece of S***!

Answer (score 0):

I tested and modified Bangline solution:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td height="117" colspan="4" background="afbeeldingen/klein-2kolom_04.gif">
          <a href="index.html">&nbsp;</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
</table>

td a {
  display:block;
  height: 117px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gSVhP/2/

Comment: hmm yeah the table would need dimensions. Ive made a quick update on the fiddle to remove `height` from the link css - http://jsfiddle.net/KyDsp/1/

Comment: I find out that it has nothing to do with the code. The image is integrated into another image, so I can not edit it. It is not my code and not my design, so one big puzzle.

Thank you all for your help, but it's better to give up this piece of S***!