# How to make my <td> which has a background image linkable?

Tags: html

```
<tbody>
             <tr>
                   <td valign="top" align="center" bgcolor="#3f76bf" style="background-position: center; background-size: cover; border-radius: 6px; background-color: #3f76bf; background-image: url('https://mcusercontent.com/73b8e8571a2f854d4f817a5c8/images/1a986052-d10d-4bf7-890f-133862bc982f.png')" background="https://mcusercontent.com/73b8e8571a2f854d4f817a5c8/images/1a986052-d10d-4bf7-890f-133862bc982f.png">
```

I would like to make the image in the td tag a hyper link, never imagined I would be spending 5 hours on this simple question.  Seems I can not just wrap in  tag. So frustrated and appreciative of your help.

Comment: Why not add a link and give that the background instead of the `td`?

Comment: Isn't there normally an src value you can assign to the object or maybe an onclick value to tell it to act as a hyperlink? Or am I getting confused?

Comment: `src` will not work on a `td` and an `onclick` is just bad practice and not accessible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making an image link in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820230/making-an-image-link-in-a-table)

Comment: You can't wrap a `td` with `a`.  If an image is meant to be  clickable, it should be part of your document via an `img` tag, NOT a background image.

Comment: Yes please don't wrap an `td` tag with an anchor tag.

Comment: @dominik Wouldn't that change the whole design?

Comment: It depends on your design of course but no, you can make the HTML look like your design which is a better way of going about it then making you CSS different so that HTML looks the right way

Comment: If you are using a `table` for layout in anything other than an HTML email, your are doing it wrong.

Comment: @Domink so essentially just changed the td tag into an a tag? I tried that and the element completely goes away, I can't see it.

Comment: @JonP this is for an email newsletter

Comment: I've added my answer. That should work even in HTML emails.

Comment: Ahh, that makes more sense, but you really should use `<td><a href=''><img src></a></td>` . Also to stop people like me jumping down your throat for using tables for layout you should mention in your question it's an HTML email :)

Comment: @JonP thx mate...For some reason, the code I have does not use a td closing tag. When I add a td closing tag, the whole element/image disappears

Comment: Oh yeah, you need that closing `td` otherwise you'll get all sorts of random behavior. Validate the HTML through a validatror to find any other missing tags. And I feel for you HTML emails should not be this difficult in 2020.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote up a more semantic way for doing what you're doing. Of course I don't know what the rest of your code looks like and you may have to tweak things. Generally it's not a good idea to use tables for layout. But I don't know how you're using it so I keep it as is.

*(Tables should only be used for tabular data)*

From the comments I can see you're using this in an HTML email where using tables for layout is still appropriate due to bad support for modern features. I have in-lined the styles for you in the example

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;background-color: #3f76bf;">
        <a href="https://yoururl.tld">
          <img style="max-width: 100%;" src="https://mcusercontent.com/73b8e8571a2f854d4f817a5c8/images/1a986052-d10d-4bf7-890f-133862bc982f.png" alt="Describe the content of the image for someone who can't see the image">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

### Update

I have since learned why they would use background images (for the images to be an equal grid) and for that I wanted to also add a solution which might be closer to your specific use case. Just a reminder to everyone that below code should not be used anywhere but in emails.

```css
/* Ignore this CSS completely for your example */
/* It's just here for the example in SO to look nice */
td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td
        valign="top"
        align="center"
        bgcolor="#3f76bf"
        style="
          position: relative;
          background-position: center;
          background-size: cover;
          border-radius: 6px;
          background-color: #3f76bf;
          background-image: url('https://mcusercontent.com/73b8e8571a2f854d4f817a5c8/images/1a986052-d10d-4bf7-890f-133862bc982f.png');
        "
        background="https://mcusercontent.com/73b8e8571a2f854d4f817a5c8/images/1a986052-d10d-4bf7-890f-133862bc982f.png"
      >
        <a href="https://yoururl.tld" style="
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          right: 0;
          botom: 0;
          left: 0;
        ">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works mostly (quite happy to see), but as you can see here:https://imgur.com/a/QFuM6G2.  it makes the image smaller than it is supposed to be for some reason

Comment: I can see now why they would have used background images. They want them in a grid and all the same size and are happy to cut thing off on either side for ascetics...

Comment: @Chucky787 I have added another example for you that might be closer to your use-case. Hope it works. Feel free to mark this the answer if it does.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a SPAN element inside the  element. It should expand to fill the space. Wrap your link around the Span and put your link-able content inside the span

```
<td><a href="#"><span>CLICK ME DON KICK ME</span></a></td>
```

If span does not work try using a  element or a .